# How to create a pivot table laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple blog in which I have a post which contains title and tags, now I want the user to be able to add tags, according to docs I needed to create a pivot table using the name convention.

Posts table on PHPMyAdmin

```
id   title
1    Death
2    Love
```

Tags table on PHPMyAdmin

```
id   name
```

Here is my migration for creating a pivot table

```
<?php

class CreatePostTagTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('post_tag');
    }
}
```

Now when I run `PHP artisan migrate` I get the following error.

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `royalad`.`#sql-ee8_307` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `post_tag` add constraint `post_tag_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`))
```

What am I doing wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();` to `$table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();` In your `tag_id` also.

Comment: Because foreign keys must match format with local keys

Comment: by the way you don't need foreign keys at all when creating a pivot table

Comment: Thanks a lot solved the problem, they should add this to docs for a newbie would be useful

Comment: we send pull requests to the docs all the time and they refuse it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯